# Why am I getting "potentially invalid reference access to a class field via this in a nested function" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

In vanilla JS, my code would work fine.  For this case, I'd like to componentize my `Wall` class which's supposed to display the image in the browser that the user has uploaded.  Again, this works normally in vanilla JS but not JSX.

I'm getting a `potentially invalid reference access to a class field via this in a nested function` on the `document.querySelector("#file-input").addEventListener("change", this.previewImages);` line which I think is causing the issue.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Wall extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.previewImages = this.previewImages.bind(this);
    }

    previewImages() {
        let preview = document.createElement("div");

        if (this.files) {
            [].forEach().call(this.files, readAndPreview());
        }

        function readAndPreview() {
            if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
                return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
            }

            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                let image = new Image();
                image.height = 100;
                image.title = file.name;
                image.src = this.result;

                let date = Date.now();
                let d = new Date(parseInt(date, 10));
                let ds = d.toString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");
                console.log(ds);

                let initialCountOfLikes = 0;
                let zeroLikes = document.createElement("h1");
                let zeroLikesTextNode = zeroLikes.createTextNode(initialCountOfLikes + " likes");

                zeroLikes.appendChild(zeroLikesTextNode);

                preview.appendChild(image); // makes image appear
                preview.appendChild(zeroLikes); // makes like count appear

                image.ondblclick = function() {
                    if (initialCountOfLikes === 0) {
                        console.log("Inside if block");
                        initialCountOfLikes++;
                        console.log("initialCountOfLikes++ => " + initialCountOfLikes);
                    } else if (initialCountOfLikes === 1) {
                        console.log("inside second else if block");
                        initialCountOfLikes--;
                        console.log("initialCountOfLikes-- => " + initialCountOfLikes);
                    }
                    zeroLikesTextNode.nodeValue = initialCountOfLikes + " likes";
                };
            });
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            document.querySelector("#file-input").addEventListener("change", this.previewImages);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="file-input-wrapper">
                <input type="file" />
                <label htmlFor="file-input" id={"LblBrowse"} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Wall;
```

Comment: Which line throws the error, exactly? Consider removing the unnecessary code. See [MCVE]

Comment: Is this a standalone component? I can't find any element with the id `#file-input`. and react has a specific way (though is not really necessary) to communicate with dom, I think its `ref`, you should probably avoid using `querySelector` directly.

Answer (score 34):

The warning is telling you that using `this` in JavaScript frequently has confusing implications, specifically when used inside a function nested inside another function. `this` stops referring to the class, and instead refers to the scope of your nested function.

In your case, this probably is a legitimate problem (I think) because you have your class, `Wall`, which has a method `previewImages()` and a property `files`. Within that function, you have instantiated a new function, `readAndPreview()`, inside which you specify `this.previewImages` as a function callback to the `addEventListener` function.

They're saying you're potentially using `this.previewImages` incorrectly, because you're writing functions in traditional JavaScript syntax, `function foo() { ... }`, where `this` keeps being redefined in each child function call. In your case, I *believe* that `this` is referring to the context of `readAndPreview()`, and hence cannot access the method `this.previewImages()` since `this` doesn't refer to your parent class, `Wall`.

People used to do things like, make a `var that = this;` on the parent class, and you'd know that `that` always meant the parent class.

But now, with ES6 lambda functions using the "fat arrow" syntax `() => { }` you can access `this` and know it's referring to the parent scope.

I believe you can refactor your class to change `previewImages() {` into `previewImages = () => {` and know that `this` will refer to the class. You'll have to do the same with `function readAndPreview() {`. Change it to `const readAndPreview = () => {`. If you're setting it to a variable, though, I think you'll have to move it above the place you call it, though. e.g. above

```
if (this.files) {
    [].forEach().call(this.files, readAndPreview());
}
```

Answer (score 25):

I faced this error in Angular 8.
I used the Arrow function instead of regular functions to solve.

In your case.

```js
readAndPreview = () => { ... }
```

This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using of arrow function may help you. Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to this, arguments or super.